# Send info from Netsuite to Magento Api

Tags: magento, netsuite, magento-1.12

I am trying to send info from Netsuite to Magento, via Magento API. In a normal condition, I execute

```
    $user       =   'user';
    $pass       =   'password';

    $url        =   'http://example.hosting.com/magento/api/soap/?wsdl';
    $webClient  =   new SoapClient($url);
    $webSession =   $webClient->login($user, $pass);

    $result     =   $webClient->call($webSession, 'ApiMethod', 'data');
```

Buy I don´t undestand how make it in a Script of Netsuite. I found a method nlapiRequestURL, but I don´t understand how make the login and send the session.

Thanks.

Comment: You may also want to consider running the sync code in magento.

Comment: We have a product that can help with this, feel free to contact us for more information - http://www.productearthsolutions.com/contact-us/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning on hosting code within NetSuite to talk to Magento, you'd probably be better served using Magento's [REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html) since it will be much easier to use. Otherwise you'd need a [Javascript SOAP client](https://github.com/gtathub/js-soap-client), which isn't part of NetSuite and unlikely to work correctly in that environment.

With the REST API, you basically hit different endpoints for each type of record e.g.

- http://magentohost/api/rest/orders for Sales Orders
- http://magentohost/api/rest/stockitems for inventory items

Then you parse your response for the data you need, or post the data you want to create.

Comment: Definitely recommend working with a REST API as well, especially if it's JSON. `nlapiRequestURL` is the right method to use to call these REST APIs from NetSuite as well.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that REST is the trick. I will investigate more. Thanks!